# Google Mini - phrase matching

Tags: google-search-appliance

is there a setting in the google mini search appliance that allows you to control how sensitive the results are? for example, searching for the phrase "building permit" will return results; searching for "building permit zoo" will return none. can i get it to give me results containing any of the words? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there's no actual sensitivity parameter, but you can use the alternate advanced search parameters to search for the following:

as_q: with all of the words
as_epq: with the exact phrase
as_oq: with at least one of the words
as_eq: without the words

Rather than the standard q parameter.

These work (mostly) the same as the advanced search parameters on google.com: http://www.google.co.uk/advanced_search?hl=en